# The smallest Fibonacci number that can be divided by $2^m$

Tags: divisibility, fibonacci-numbers, big-numbers

How can i calculate the smallest **Fibonacci** number that can be divided by $2^m$ (a big number). I tried computing  with a dynamic algorithm but it reaches a point where my RAM simply can't carry on. Any ideas?

Comment: is $m$ fixed or do you just need any Fibonacci number that is a power of $2$?

Comment: $m$ is fixed . (thanks for the edit btw , couldn't figure out how to format it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should look at this summary [The Fibonacci Sequence Modulo m](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fib.htm) by Marc Renault.
It contains a lot of information about divisibility properties of Fibonacci sequences.

According to section D. "Facts on the rank of $F  \pmod m$" on above summary,

> The smallest Fibonacci number that can be divided by $2^m$ is $F_{\alpha(2^m)}$ where
>   $$\alpha(2) = 3,\quad\alpha(2^2) = 6\quad\text{ and }\quad \alpha(2^m) = 6\cdot 2^{m-3} \quad\text{ for } m \ge 3$$

Look at there for related results and references.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed . The lecture is interesting too.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci numbers, mod $2^m$, are periodic, with period less than $2^{m+1}$. Further, the period begins with $0,1$.   For a proof, see [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/assignments/199S/FibModK.pdf).

Hence, once they begin to repeat, you will get a Fibonacci number with $2^m$ as divisor.  You can do all computations modulo $2^m$, which hopefully won't overtax your RAM.

Comment: I got your point. However I fail to see how i can compute it. If $m$ is big , wouldn't looking for the period take a very long time too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of your calculations mod $2^n$ to start. For example, if you wanted to find the smallest n such that $2^m | F_n$ with m = 2 you can keep track of the remainder of $F_i$ and $F_{i+1}$ mod 4. This would proceed like so:

$$F_1 = 1 \,mod\, 4$$
$$F_2 = 1 \,mod\, 4$$
$$F_3 = 2 \,mod\, 4$$
$$F_4 = 3 \,mod\, 4$$
$$F_5 = 1 \,mod\, 4$$
$$F_6 = 0 \,mod\, 4$$

And you could then conclude that $F_6$ is the smallest Fibonacci divisible by $2^2$ and then use an alternate method to calculate the value of $F_6$. The advantage of this method is that you only need to keep track of two numbers of m bits which represent the last two remainders. Adding these two remainders is very straightforward as well and should not burden your computer too much.

Comment: I already did that before. It had given really good results compared to my very first  program , but it failed to find the solution (reached around $n =1800000$ ).

Comment: I was surprised , but my tought is the number itself becomes so big that it floods the memory.

Comment: Then this becomes more of a programming problem than a math problem. Adding two numbers modulo $2^m$ is a very inexpensive operation, it is either identical or very similar to repeating XOR. You should only be holding on to the two most recent remainders at any time so that is a $2*m$ bits and then however many bits you are using to keep track of $n$. Depending on the language you are using, you should try to find a datatype like longInt in Java or C to keep track of $n$. What scale is the $m$ that you are using?

Comment: I should check for $m=32$ , I noticed that it's a power of 2 (so basically my number should be devided by 2, 32 times .However , this couldn't get me any further)

Comment: I had a ")" error on my code. My problem is solved. Thanks!